# Why can we not continue physics calculations on false vacuum?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, perturbation-theory

I understand that starting with some vacuum state, it may transition to another vacuum if it exists. Howver we can technically represent a vacuum in terms of another vacuum.
So why can we not do this, and we have to do calculations around the closest vacuum?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/406159/2451